# Add popup link of different module in Grid with Order ID

Tags: magento-1.8, grid, controllers

I have override Grid.php of Order Grid, I want to add popup to link another module. I need to pass order ID to controller using url of popup link.
please check below code

```
class Mycompany_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{
    public $url;

     protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $test=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
            $array = array();
            foreach ($test as $_index=>$_item){
            $array[] = $_item->getId();
            }
            $OrderId=array_reverse($array);
            foreach($OrderId as $key=>$OrderIdValue){
            $this->url= $this->getUrl('*/module/index/', array('order_id' => $OrderIdValue)); // url generated correctly here
            $this->addColumn('upload',
                array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('core')->__('Pop up'),
                    'width'     => '50px',
                    'type'      => 'action',
                    'getter'     => 'getId',
                    'actions'   => array(
                        array(
                            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Pop up'),
                            'onclick' =>"return myPop('".$this->url."')"   // generates only one url like /module/index/order_id/1
                        )
                    ),
                    'filter'    => false,
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'index'     => 'stores',
                    'is_system' => true,
            ));


    } // for each ends here 

 return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }



}
```

I'm not able to iterate **order_id**  here `'onclick' =>"return myPop('".$this->url."')"`

Comment: For me the code works and the url is built as follows. `admin/module/index/order_id/1/key/da0ea4f3d15a07e8eda8705612086eb8/` what is the url that is displayed for you?

Comment: @David only this url generated, for order id 7 it must show
`admin/module/index/order_id/7/key/da0ea4f3d15a07e8eda8705612086eb8/` instead of 
`admin/module/index/order_id/1/key/da0ea4f3d15a07e8eda8705612086eb8/`

Comment: Ah no i see the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Solution was very each , use of sales- order model `$test=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();` was waste of time.
I used `'popup'   => true` this syntax to get pop up window. I knew this syntax , but i thought it renders only Grid Url not other custom link.

```
array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('core')->__('Pop up'),
                    'width'     => '50px',
                    'type'      => 'action',
                    'getter'     => 'getId',
                    'actions'   => array(
                        array(
                            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Pop up'),
                            'url'     => array('base'=>'*/module/index'),
                            'field'   => 'order_id',
                    'popup'   => true
                        )
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each column in the `_prepareColumns` is processed on a row basis any way so what happens with your loop is it will add a column for each order but since the name is not unique then they will override each other and the last one will be taken. Hence why you are seeing only the final url. You do not need to loop through the orders yourself as Magento will do this when building the gird, I think as part of the `_prepareColumns`.

For a normal url the following will work.

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('upload',
        array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('core')->__('Pop up'),
            'width'     => '50px',
            'type'      => 'action',
            'getter'     => 'getId',
            'actions'   => array(
                array(
                    'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Pop up'),
                    'url'     => array('base'=>'*/module/index'),
                    'field'   => 'order_id'
                )
            ),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,
            'index'     => 'stores',
            'is_system' => true,
        ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

This will add the order id from each row to build the correct url. Currently I am not sure how to add an onClick with this information.

Comment: method used here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4449/link-for-action-column-in-custom-grid.
and used by me is almost same but they have successfully rendered url

Comment: @Aad yes that is the same as the code I have given you, this will work for a normal link but not for an onClick option.

Comment: sorry i haven't mentioned in above comment
even if you use `url=>$this->url` you will get same url

Comment: @Aad yes you do not need the `$this->url` or the foreach as the grid will add the information as part of the prepareCollection call. If you remove the looping and update your code to match my answer then at least the link itself will be generated correctly.